# how to clone a project from gitlab to android studio using strictly gitbash only

Tags: git, gitlab

This sounds silly, But for a new comer like me finding the right tutorial is really a great deal. I asked Mr. Google about GitLab and he always showing me about GitHub. Some how i got to know to clone from GitHub from Android Studio itself But i don't want that.

I need step by step guidance to clone a project from GitLab to Android Studio using GitBash in windows 10.

I need an answer, So that a new comer can easily understand the flow. Thank you

Comment: what did you learn after your google search?  `git clone repo_uri` does it not serve your need?

Comment: @user404 the thing is I'm a guest there and i cannot see the proper uri. so i just copied the uri from url bar and appended .git at last and it didn't worked. failed to clone. and also how to load that clone into android studio by command line of gitbash?

Comment: you will find the `repo_uri` from your gitab repository upper-left corner with text `clone` , click on it, you will see two options, copy the link with `http` option and do what I said in previous comment. Make sure you open your git bash from that folder where you want yo have your code. Moreover, check the link attached in your question

Comment: @user404 i see only this. https://ibb.co/3rPH4m9  . what you said was not there check yourself

Comment: You do not have access to the project's repository/source code. You cannot clone it. Ask the project admin to give you the proper permissions.

Comment: @user404 you are right. thats why I'm asking steps to get started and other failure things which comes in the scenario to learn. but someone marked my project as duplicate.

Comment: @VikasAcharya, check this [git easy](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/using-git-and-github-on-windows)